# How to use inline-block properly to position elements?

Tags: css, sass

I have an image, a title and a description.
I want to display the image on the left and then show the title and description next to it.

This is pretty easy with floats, but is it possible using inline-block? Can't figure out how to show it properly without using floats.

What is the proper way to do this? Are floats "bad" to use?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1euvcbx

```css
.path-team {
        text-align: left;
        .item-list {
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .list-item {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .field__item {
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            p {
                font-weight: normal;
                padding-bottom: 25px;
            }
            img {
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                padding: 0;
            }
        }
        /* positioning */
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            li {}
            ul {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="path-team">

<ul class="item-list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="field-collection-item">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="field field--name-field-picture">
          <div class="field__item">
            <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/e201976d7a4fd5745d9cc1af713943b4.png" alt="Sofie">
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="field field--name-team-name">
          <div class="field__item">
            Sofie
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="field field--name-team-short-desc">
          <div class="field__item">
            <p>
              Bunch of text goes in here.
              Could be multiple lines of text.
              It's a description of the person.
              To the left we want the persons picture.
              At the top to the right of the picture we want the persons name in bold.
              Below that we want this text.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

This is what I have now:

[image: start]

What I want as end result:

[image: result]

Comment: You have to use float to achieve this as simple, there is no harm of using float if you clear them as necessary. or else you also can use display:table and display:table-cell to position these but I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: _“What is the proper way to do this? Are floats "bad" to use?”_ – floats aren’t inherently “bad,” no. They just weren’t intended to be a tool to base a whole layout on - but they were “the best we had” for a long time, and often the only feasible alternative to using tables for column layouts. Today we have better layout tools available though - namely flexbox. And grid layout is the next big thing to arrive in browsers in that regard. But using floats or inline-block in a situation like this is fine, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no problems with floats in themselves However, if you want to rely on `inline-block`, you could do something like this:

Add the name and description tags in a new `div` tag, like so:

```
<div class="info-container">
    <div class="field field--name-team-name">
      <div class="field__item">
        Sofie
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field field--name-team-short-desc">
      <div class="field__item">
        <p>
          Bunch of text goes in here.
          Could be multiple lines of text.
          It's a description of the person.
          To the left we want the persons picture.
          At the top to the right of the picture we want the persons name in bold.
          Below that we want this text.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then add these css rules:

```
.field-name-field-picture, .info-container {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}

.info-container {
   width: 300px;
}
```

(Note that the two hyphens were removed in `.field-name-field-picture`, that's because two consecutive hyphens makes an invalid class.)

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1euvcbx/7/).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this layout. Generally I would recommend either using `display: inline-block` or `display: flex`. If you can't decide which way to go always check the support, in your case for [display: inline-block](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block) and [display: flex](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Also you could simplify your HTML structure to this. This will work for both solutions.

**HTML**

```
<div class="field">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/192651/pexels-photo-192651.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Title">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p> Bunch of text goes in here. Could be multiple lines of text. It's a description of the person. To the left we want the persons picture. At the top to the right of the picture we want the persons name in bold. Below that we want this text. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **display: inline-block**

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.field {
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.field img,
.field .content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.field img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30%;
}

.field .content {
   width: 70%;
   font-size: initial;
   padding: 10px 20px;
}

.content h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.field {
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.field img,
.field .content {
  display: inline-block;
}
.field img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 30%;
}
.field .content {
  width: 70%;
  font-size: initial;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.content h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/192651/pexels-photo-192651.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Title">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>
      Bunch of text goes in here. Could be multiple lines of text. It's a description of the person. To the left we want the persons picture. At the top to the right of the picture we want the persons name in bold. Below that we want this text.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### display: flex

**CSS**

```
.field {
  width: 50%;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.field .content {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.content h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
.field {
  width: 50%;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
img {
  max-width: 100px;
}
.field .content {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.content h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/192651/pexels-photo-192651.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" alt="Title">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>
      Bunch of text goes in here. Could be multiple lines of text. It's a description of the person. To the left we want the persons picture. At the top to the right of the picture we want the persons name in bold. Below that we want this text.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```